# How to determine which files are on SSD on Fusion Drive?

Tags: macos, fusion-drive

My question is:

> How can i determine which files are on the SSD "partition" on Fusion
>   Drive?

I have an iMac with 1TB Fusion Drive, and it would be good to know which apps or data are on which partition.

> Is these information included in the file information or where do i
>   have to look?

Terminal is no problem, so i'm not searching for a easy answer.

EDIT: `diskutil list` shows me my partitions. But i cannot navigate through /Volumes/... into the specific SSD partition. There must be a way to navigate into each partition, right?

OS X does the same.

Comment: This isn't an answer but is definitely worth a look: 

http://www.anandtech.com/show/6679/a-month-with-apples-fusion-drive

The author uses [iStat Menus 4](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25230/istat-menus) to view disk activity of the individual devices, you can see them on page 3, "Under The Hood."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because the Fusion drive is one [logical volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management), there are no separate "partitions" to browse to determine this. You can however check which drive an given file is stored on with some command-line utilities.

### Determine Your Drive Setup

First we have to figure out how the SSD and HD portions of the Fusion drive are identified in your system.

1. Run `diskutil list` in Terminal.
2. You should see output similar to this:

   ```
   #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
   0: GUID_partition_scheme *121.3 GB disk0
   1: EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1
   2: Apple_CoreStorage 121.0 GB disk0s2
   3: Apple_Boot Boot OS X 134.2 MB disk0s3
   /dev/disk1
   #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
   0: GUID_partition_scheme *1.0 TB disk1
   1: EFI 209.7 MB disk1s1
   2: Apple_CoreStorage 999.3 GB disk1s2
   3: Apple_Boot Recovery HD 650.0 MB disk1s3
   /dev/disk2
   #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
   0: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD *1.1 TB disk2
   ```
3. Take note of labels of the disks with a `GUID_partition_scheme` line. In this case, that's `disk0` and `disk1`. These are the two physical disks, and we can see by the sizes, the smaller one (`disk0`) is the SSD, meaning `disk1` is the HD while `disk2` is the logical volume.

### Monitor Disk Activity

Now we need a way to monitor disk activity for each device.

1. Open Terminal, enter `iostat -d disk0 disk1 1`, *replacing the disk numbers with those you found in above*.
2. Run the command, and leave the Terminal window open. You should see output similar to this:

   ```
          disk0           disk1 
    KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s 
    26.52  13  0.33     9.35   0  0.00 
    0.00   0  0.00     0.00   0  0.00 
    0.00   0  0.00     0.00   0  0.00 
    0.00   0  0.00     0.00   0  0.00
   ```

   This shows you the disk activity on a per-device basis, updated every second. The MB/s columns are the most relevant.

### Read a File

Now we'll read a file, and use our monitoring solution to discover which drive it resides on.

1. Open a second Terminal window, and run `dd if='/path/to/some/file' of=/dev/null`. Replace the path with the proper path to the file (be sure it's quoted if it has unescaped spaces or other special characters).
2. In the terminal window running `iostat`, watch the to see which disk shows some activity when `dd` is running. That's the drive the file resides on.
3. For large files (especially those on the HD, the dd process may run for a while, you can safely quit it with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Readings like this indicate that `disk0` (the SSD in this example) contains the file:

```
       disk0           disk1 
 KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s 
 28.49  13  0.37   113.92   0  0.00 
 31.70 4500 139.29     0.00   0  0.00 
 31.64 3870 119.56     0.00   0  0.00 
 31.58 3294 101.58     0.00   0  0.00
```

Whereas these readings indicate that the file is stored on the HD:

```
       disk0           disk1 
 KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s 
 0.00   0  0.00   128.00 275 34.33 
 0.00   0  0.00   128.00 255 31.83 
 7.62  53  0.39   126.90 178 22.03
```

Comment: That's great! Thank's a lot! But there are always smaller writes to the drive. Even if i don't do anything. Plus a delay when i execute the "dd". For smaller files (10MB), there is a "problem". But if i execute the dd, there are, after 3 seconds, always on the "ssd"-side transactions...so maybe this helps!

Comment: Depending on the access patterns and how long you've been using your Fusion drive, accessing a file once or twice may be enough for the system to "promote" it to the SSD, in which case you may see access on both, so it's unfortunately not foolproof, but it should be enough for a good guess.

Comment: But a question: Why doesn't the "df "filename" command doesn't show the right partition? It only shows "disk2".

Comment: Because Fusion doesn't work with traditional partitions. `disk2` in is the logical volume created by joining the two drives. From the filesystem's point of view, that is where the file lives, but it's independent of where the underlying bits are physically stored. You might want to read up on [how the Fusion drive works](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/10/more-on-fusion-drive-how-it-works-and-how-to-roll-your-own/) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears robmathers' methodology breaks with Apple's new APFS, where the lower level implementation of Fusion drive logical volumes has changed. Trying the above results in:
iostat: could not record 'disk1' for monitoring

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Fusion Drives work at the block level, not at the file level, so theoretically, one file could be split across both volumes.

Answer (score -2):

If you want that much control over which files go where, it's easy enough to break up the fusion drive and just have two separate volumes you can navigate separately. It's also very easy in OS X to have the OS including applications on one drive (the SSD) and have the user account live on a different drive (the HDD). Then you can manually manage where you want other files, the SSD or the HDD.

Comment: I think the question is referring not to how to break it but how to determine where files have automatically been sorted.

Comment: This answer is useful though, but maybe it should have been a comment.