# My SSD works on every computer except mine

Tags: macos, hard-drive, hardware, ssd

I've [asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158463/fix-a-diy-fusion-drive) [several](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159257/os-x-install-on-ssd-hangs-every-time) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162982/ssd-issue-trim-related) on Ask Different about an Intel SSD that I'd bought and tried to use in a DIY Fusion Drive in my early 2011 13" MBP. The Fusion Drive worked for a few weeks and then quit on me. The HDD works fine, but  whenever I try and install OS X on the SSD, it hangs right around the part of the installation where the logs say it's extracting all the packages. The first extraction took around 15 minutes, but the next one hadn't moved after an hour. I'm resurrecting this topic because today I decided to play with it at the IT company where I'm interning this summer, and my boss and I ran a few experiments that made things a whole lot more interesting...

Things that work perfectly:

- Installing Linux Mint on it on a PC
- Installing Windows 10 on it
- Installing Mavericks on it when it's plugged into my sister's computer (mid-2012 13" MBP)

Things that don't work:

- Installing Mavericks, Yosemite, and the El Cap Public Beta when the SSD is plugged into my computer (they all hung)
- An un-SSDlike boot time (several minutes) when I plugged it into my computer after having given it Mavericks with my sister's computer

So, why does my SSD only hate my hardware? I'd get it if it was a bad drive, but apparently the thing is in proper working order if it's plugged into any computer except mine. What's going on???

Comment: I would come up with a recommendation and a question. Recommendation is to use a USB enclosure to try that drive. The question is, it could be a bad cable !

Comment: @Buscar웃SD It's not a bad cable. My HDD works fine, and the SSD works fine on Linux and Windows in a PC. The only problematic scenario is the SSD in my MBP.

Comment: Do you use same cable for HD and SSD ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Yeah. The SATA logic board connector that came with the computer.

Comment: machine struggling to step down SATA 3 6Gb/s to SATA 2 3Gb/s? [just a guess]

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm pretty sure the computer supports SATA 3.

Comment: @Tetsujin Intel's website says the SSD supports SATA 3.

Comment: @user24601 Does your machine actually hang (mouse cursor not moving) or does the Mac OS installation just stop progressing? Is there anything in the installation log when the freeze happens (*Window* > *Installer Log*)?

Comment: @mjturner The cursor was still moving, but the install was moving ridiculously slowly. In the attempted Mavericks installation (which got the furthest before I gave up), I'd seen times when no new log entries would come up for an hour and a half. I'd give up entirely when the progress bar stopped inching forward for quite a long time. On the Yosemite/El Cap installs, the progress bar stopped while the log was at one of the early package extractions, but on Mavericks, it got as far as running a kextcache command before slowing to a halt.